# Exporting UAV coordinates from Mission Planner GCS

Tags: mission-planner

I want to export UAV coordinates lat, long, alt from Mission Planner GCs using UDP socket communication. Can anyone guide me, from which file of mission planner src, i have to export them?

I am currently customizing Mission Planner src for exporting UAV coordinates but i don't know the exact file from where i will retrieve these coordinates.